# SQL injection login bypass

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am preparing SQL injection vulnerable page to test skills, here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "<center><h1>Login Bypass</h1></center>";
    include 'config.php';
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $passwd = $_REQUEST['passwd'];
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$name' AND password = '$passwd'";
    echo "<center>".$query_string."</center><br/>";
    $query = mysql_query($query_string) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
        echo "<center>SUCCESS</center><br/>";
    else echo "<center>ACCESS DENIED</center><br/>";
    echo "<center>".$row['email']."</center><br/>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Login Bypass</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.19.1" />
</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <form action="login_bypass.php" method="get">
        Login: <input name="name">
        Password: <input name="passwd" >
        <input type="submit" value="CHECK">
    </form>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also table users where I have username='agajan' and password='12345' email='torayeff@gmail.com'.
I know that this query is vulnerable:

```
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$name' AND password = '$passwd'";
```

But when I insert instead of username the following "agajan' /*" and leave password field empty I  get:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'agajan' /* ' AND password = ' '
```

...but It gives me mysql error.  Can anyone explain me why I can not inject sql?

Comment: You need to format your code properly for it to be readable.  Use 4+ spaces, not the `pre` tag.

Comment: close the comment as well with */ or you can use a double dash -- to comment out the rest of the line instead of using /**/ which would work in your situation as well.

Comment: @Craig, I don't think `--` would work, as password is checked in another line, so that line would not be commented.

Comment: @binaryLV, It is not on another line.. @Paul Schreiber, edited and formatted the code to be more legible, but in doing so altered the functionality of the code/answers.. I have reverted that part back to its original state.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli, my bad, did not look at original question.

Answer (score 4):

you don't close your comment.  Try

"agajan' ; --"

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
 WHERE username = 'agajan'; --  ' AND password = ' '
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you did not close your C-style comment cleanly, so you have managed a syntax error in your comment.  Use a double-dash `--` comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid comment because you use the inline comment which requires a closing `*/` as well..

Use `--` or `#` comments instead, so you need to pass `agajan' --` or `agajan' #`.

MySql comment syntax : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Answer (score 0):

Because the SQL statement itself is not valid.  It doesn't pass the test of proper formatting.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
 WHERE username = 'agajan' /* ' AND password = ' '
```

Consider input like "agajan'; SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user = 'agajan'"

```
UPDATE users 
 SET priv = 'superuser'
 WHERE username = 'agajan'; SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'agajan' AND password = ' '
```

Comment: It is actual injection (*of code*), since you can bypass login authentication by dropping the password check..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot ";" before $username